# How to load 3D model from a 3ds file using AssimpNet in C# (SharpDX)?

Tags: c#, sharpdx, assimp, 3d-model, 3ds

I want to load and display a 3ds file in C# using SharpDX. To load 3ds file I found a tool 'Assimp' and got a wrapper for C# [AssimpNet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AssimpNet/).

How to load 3ds using AssimpNet?
I don't see any importer available in assimpnet.

Comment: You could use the handful function to check if the extension is supported `IsExtensionSupported` [(source)](https://github.com/assimp/assimp-net/blob/f3e7daab8baa6c61d75f4213fcdad6f0db2cac60/AssimpNet/Unmanaged/AssimpLibrary.cs). If it is supported, maybe you should learn how the *.3ds file load by Assimp, and then implement it in AssimpNet.

Answer (score 1):

```
Assimp.Scene model;
Assimp.AssimpContext importer = new Assimp.AssimpContext();
importer.SetConfig(new Assimp.Configs.NormalSmoothingAngleConfig(66.0f));
model = importer.ImportFile(filename, Assimp.PostProcessPreset.TargetRealTimeMaximumQuality);
```